# Bash Date - Why does adding seconds increment the hour?

Tags: bash, date

I'm struggling to understand the results from the following date commands:

```
$ date --date "2020-10-03T17:49:23" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
2020-10-03T17:49:23
$ date --date "2020-10-03T17:49:23 + 1 second" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
2020-10-03T17:49:24
$ date --date "2020-10-03T17:49:23 + 2 second" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
2020-10-03T16:49:24
$ date --date "2020-10-03T17:49:23 + 2 seconds" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
2020-10-03T16:49:24
$ date --date "2020-10-03T17:49:23 - 2 seconds" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
2020-10-03T20:49:24
```

Adding a single second appears to work, but anything more (or less) decrements (or increments) the hour by various amounts.

What am I missing?

Comment: The +1 is interpreted as a timezone (UTC+1) so if your local timezone is the same, nothing happens, +2 means UTC+2 etc. Have a look at the duplicate and the link therein that explains it.

Comment: it is better to use `prev` and `next` instead of `+` and `-`

Comment: This makes perfect sense. But then why do many examples work with the + 2 seconds format? Is it due to input format of the date string? Actually - if the "+" is being seen as time zone why is a second being added at all?

Comment: It sees the string `seconds` and automatically assumes that you requested to add 1 second (the default quantity of that particular unit) The substring `2020-10-03T17:49:23 + 1` is seen as date-time + timezone. and the substring `seconds` is understood as _add one second_

Answer (score 0):

You can guard against it by adding the `--utc` option and specifying the UTC timesone in the input date string:

```sh
date --utc --date "2020-10-03T17:49:23Z + 2 second" "+%FT%T"
# ...^^^^^............................^
```

```
2020-10-03T17:49:25
```

Another way do it is to move the `+` to a different place, so the date scanner doesn't try to parse it as a `+HHMM` timezone (`+HHMM` can be written as `+HH` with the minute offset taken as zero; and `+HH` can be written with one digit as `+H`)

```sh
date --date "2020-10-03 +2 second 17:49:23" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
date --date "+2 second 2020-10-03T17:49:23" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
```

Refer to [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats) in the GNU date manual.

Comment: While it is true that you can use the military timezone notation, but this might not be in line with what the OP wants. Especially when it boils down to day-light saving.